# Converting Excel VBA Add-Ins to Office JS Add-In - Can it do what I need?

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, office-js, office-addins

I've spent the last two weeks getting my Office JS Add-In dev environment setup, what a pain! Before I keep spending more time on it, I wondered if the Office JS can even do some of the things I need to replace my VBA Add-Ins.

Things include:

- I often scrape web page tables, I'm pretty sure I can do this w/ JS
- I have some macros that need to interact with webpage before scraping, such as input data and click a button, can Office Add-In interact with an external webpage in this fashion?
- I have a bunch of macros which fire off a URL w/ params that spits back a Spreadsheet either in the format of downloading an `xlsx` or Excel just opens the spreadsheet. I currently have two macros for this, one finds the file on the FileSystem and imports it, the other, finds the Excel instance (separate from the open/existing instance) and imports the spreadsheet. I have a feeling Office JS can't do either of these, but I can possibly look into converting these to scraping, but I'm not 100%.
- Is there a way for me to import my VBA Add-In via a JS Add-In (I don't think so since I don't have FS access from JS, but that would resolve any issues I can't do in JS).

The reason I'm looking to port away from VBA is I don't think Corp likes the idea of investing in VBA, for one, its hard to find/hire VBA Devs and another is its all "unsupported" though I've got my deployment 100% figured out. If I could host Add-Ins via official channels in a "normal" programming language, they might be more interested, but I'm unsure if Office JS is the way to go?

Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your points covered in the post you really need to develop a COM add-in, not a web add-in. You can easily port your VBA macros to VSTO based add-ins where you could be using a "normal" programming language of your preference (I personally prefer using C# for COM add-ins).

There is no "automatic conversion", although to a certain extent you can copy/paste the procedures then "tweak" them for their new environment. Certainly, the simplest is to use VB.NET to create the VSTO project, rather than C#. That's because VBA and VB.NET have a similar syntax.

Then you need to decide whether you want an add-in, or a document-specific project.

Finally, you may find the [Extend Your VBA Code With VSTO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2007/august/office-apps-extend-your-vba-code-with-vsto) article helpful.

Comment: Can you expand on why? Is it not possible to webscrape?

Comment: Ive started to think the same tho, thanks!

Comment: Can VSTO show in the insert add-ins spot? I don't think it can it needs to be an installer right that was my big reason for web

Comment: Well, you need to choose between able to install via add-ins spot or implement the the required tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, I've been quite happy with migrating to Office-JS. Working w/ JS is such a pleasure compared to VBA.

Most of my old VBA macros that scrapped webpages I was able to convert by posting directly to the API's, but some I was unable to migrate such as one that opened a webpage and made selections, but didn't submit as the user was in charge of verification before submission.

I am able to import workbooks from URLs using `arrayBuffer`

I haven't looked to hard into it, but it is possible to have VBA and JS interact, but I think its hacky and the entire goal was to move away from VBA.

My biggest hurtle has been getting the Add-In uploaded to our internal MS365 exchange, which was one of the main goals, but thats possibly due to our internal infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make partial conversion to Web addin. User FreeSoftwareServers pointed out that most likely there is no way of Web Addin and VBA to interact. A possible workaround is to insert data into cells with VBA and read it with JS web addin. Of course the use of this method is limited, but may be suitable for some scenarios